# Unfinished long string near <eof>

Tags: lua, cheat-engine

```
function writeFloat([=[==[===[====["game.exe"+XXXXXXXX]+XXX====]+XXX===]+XXX==]+XXX=]+XXX, trackbar_getPosition(TRAINERFORM_CETrackBar1))
end
```

gives me the error

> [string "--code..."]:4: unfinished long string near

Comment: `[=[` starts a long string which is terminated with `]=]`. The latter is not in your code.

Comment: @siffie I thought it was ``[[``?

Comment: @warspyking: That's correct as well. `]]` closes `[[`, `]=]` closes `[=[`, `]==]` closes `[==[`, and so on.

Comment: @siffie Ohhh. Didn't even realize that

Answer (score 3):

Lua has "long strings", which are induced by the syntax of `[=*[`, where "=*" means "zero or more `=` characters". So `[[` begins a long string, as does `[==[` or `[=[`, as in your case.

A long string is so named because it accepts every character between the inducing syntax and the terminating syntax. This allows you to do useful things like add verbatim XML, C++, or even Lua code within your Lua script as a literal string.

The terminating syntax is `]=*]`, where "=*" means *the exact same number* of `=` characters that was used to induce the long string. So if you start with `[=[`, the long string will *only end* with `]=]`. `]]` and `]====]` or any other terminus will not end the long string; they'll be taken verbatim into the string.

So this:

```
local lit = [=[Long String]==]=]
```

Results in `lit` taking the value `Long String]==`.

In your code, you never see a `]=]` sequence. You have `====]` and similar things, but they don't even start with a `]` character.

It is illegal to start a long string that never ends in a Lua script. Hence the compile error.